# Brighten image with text using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, mouseover

We using this css

```
.event_box > a img{
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  transition: all 0.7s linear;
}
 .event_box >a:hover img:hover{ 
  filter:brightness(100%)
}

.event_box .text-picture
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans Semibold;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

in combination with this html:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="event_box">
                    <a href="'.$templink.$langlink.$paginalink.'portfolio'.$caselink.'1000-wishes">
                    <img src="'.$url.'images/home/1000-wishes.jpg" alt="1000 Wishes"/>
                        <div class="text-picture">
                        1000 Wishes
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

You will see a picture with text on of the picture.
The mouse over effects works till your mousepointer hits the text, then the mouse over effect stops.
Is there a sollution for this problem?

```css
.event_box > a img{
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  transition: all 0.7s linear;
}
 .event_box >a:hover img:hover{ 
  filter:brightness(100%)
}

.event_box .text-picture
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans Semibold;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="event_box">
                    <a href="http://www.jcsl.nl/clean/images/home/1000-wishes.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.jcsl.nl/clean/images/home/1000-wishes.jpg" alt="1000 Wishes">
                        <div class="text-picture">
                        1000 Wishes
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: is there any chance to update the question with a code snippet?

Comment: I never did this before, I hope it works fine like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.text-picture` CSS.

What this does is let mouse events (like hovering, clicking, etc) *pass through* the element. By doing this, the image's "hovered" state won't be interrupted, and thus it will stay bright.

```css
.event_box > a img{
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s linear;
  transition: all 0.7s linear;
}
 .event_box >a:hover img:hover{ 
  filter:brightness(100%)
}

.event_box .text-picture
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans Semibold;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="event_box">
                    <a href="http://www.jcsl.nl/clean/images/home/1000-wishes.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.jcsl.nl/clean/images/home/1000-wishes.jpg" alt="1000 Wishes">
                        <div class="text-picture">
                        1000 Wishes
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did never saw this option. Even Notepad++ does not reconise this.

Comment: No problem. [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is most often used in conjunction with SVG images, however setting it to `none` will work for all element types. It's somewhat new, but is recognized in all modern browsers, as well as IE11+. If you're looking for a solution that works pre-IE11, I can see what's available.

Answer (score 2):

Add pointer events none to the text-picture class

```
.event_box .text-picture
{
  //this line
  pointer-events:none;
  ----

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Open Sans Semibold;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 0;
}
```